# Joomla 2.5 component get json from external script

Tags: javascript, json, joomla

I would get a json (make from a db query) from a external script javascript.

my model:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die();

jimport( 'joomla.application.component.modelList' );


class MediastoreModelList extends JModelList
{
    function getListQuery()
    {
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select('id, type, designation', 'marque', 'prix');
        $query->from('produits');
        return $query;
    }
}
```

my controller:

```
<?PHP
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

class MediastoreController extends JController
{   
    public function getJson() {
        $model = getModel();
        $data = $model.getListQuery();
        $document = JFactory::getDocument();
    $document->setMimeEncoding('application/json');
    JResponse::setHeader('Content-Disposition','attachment;filename="result.json"');
    echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

my javascript:

```
$.getJSON( "http://mediastore.dev/index.php?option=com_mediastore&task=getJson", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

but the getJSON fails.
What's wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: How are you loading the jQuery library and how and where is the AJAX call made?  Joomla also uses mootools which uses the $ character as well so the first thing i would try is replacing the $ with jQuery in your JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller code will throw PHP errors. It has to look like:

```
public function getJson() {
    $model = $this->getModel();
    $data = $model->getItems();
    $document = JFactory::getDocument();
    $document->setMimeEncoding('application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
    JFactory::getApplication()->close();
}
```

Try to put the controller action to lowercase. I would also replace the $ with `jQuery` in your ajax call.
To see what is actually in the response of the ajax call I suggest to use firebug or the chrome developer console which will display the whole response and then you will find out very quick where the problem is.